# Serilog. How to filter RequestLoggin to store those logs on a different sink

Tags: .net-core, serilog

I as I have seen (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/804) it is in theory possible to filter data and divert it to different sinks.

I would like to separate my errors and logs from the access logs (Request logging).

Does anybody know what criteria is needed in order to only pass the request logging events?

`.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)`

Thanks in advance and I hope somebody can help me.

Kind Regards,
José.